# How to get unit test coverage of components run inside loop in React and Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, create-react-app

I wrote a unit test for component that spits out atomized component icons (from a custom library built from icomoon.io ) The issue I am having is that despite each component rendering correctly; the test for the component that renders each icon shows no coverage upon the check. The desired outcome is that when i 'npm run test:coverage' it shows coverage for each atomized icon component if it renders correctly in the test.

Directory

```
* constants
--* iconConstants.js
* components
--* iconGenerator
-----* iconGenerator.js
-----* icons
--------* icon1.js
--------* icon2.js
--------* icon3.js
* __tests__
--* iconGenerator
-----*iconGenerator.test.js
```

Here is the generator:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import cx from 'classnames';

// Constants
import { ICONS } from '../../constants/iconConstants';

const iconGenerator = (props) => {
    const { type, size } = props;
    const inf = ICONS[type];

    return (
        <span
            className={ cx('ne8-icon', inf.iconCls) }
            style={ { fontSize: `${size}em` } }
            title={ inf.description } />
    );
};

iconGenerator.defaultProps = {
    size: 3,
};

iconGenerator.propTypes = {
    type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    size: PropTypes.number,
};

export default iconGenerator;
```

here is the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import iconGenerator from '../../components/iconGenerator/iconGenerator.js';

import { ICONS } from '../../constants/iconConstants';

describe('iconGenerator', () => {
    const iconKeys = Object.keys(ICONS);

    for (let i = 0; i < iconKeys.length; i += 1) {
        it(`renders ${iconKeys[i]} symbol without crashing`, () => {
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            ReactDOM.render(<iconGenerator type={ iconKeys[i] } />, div);
            ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
        });
    }
});
```

When I run the test:coverage it shows 0 coverage for any of the icon.js files even though they are being rendered just fine AND that I get 100% coverage for the icongenerator.js file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not requiring or rendering any of the icon files, just the one `iconGenerator` component with many different types, which then change the classname. To get coverage on the various `icon*.js`, you'd need to require/render them, which you could also do in a loop.

Higher level, I'm not sure how your icon generator actually 'generates' icons, it looks like a regular ol' component that renders a span. Which absolutely works, of course! But it's not creating other components.

Comment: #facepalm Completely forgot I changed back to spans and the old files trickled down through a tricky merge... smh.. Thanks Eon_Cyber